# Typescript: Why does typescript allow me to call function with wrong interface type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following case.
There is no error reported by Typescript while calling func with argument of type One - why?

```
export interface One {
    common?: string
    one?: string;
}

export interface Two {
    common?: string
    two?: string;
}


export function func(arg: Two) {
    // do something!
}


const one: One = {
    common: 'common',
    one: 'One'
};

const two: Two = {
    common: 'common',
    two: 'Two'
}

func(one);
```

Comment: Can you try this in the typescript playground? Also, it’s usually a warning or error if you have an interface with zero required properties. Will your interfaces actually have only optional properties?

Comment: Did try in typescript playground, no errors or warnings :(

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIDyKBA3sApQrlALa1QoD8AXAgM5wyoDmFVjEKw5deAbmABfYKEixEqdFjwEAKgHcoCclWp0GzNp24o+uuJuHHxUmbOjwEmAK4pccJIyevcACmwwPGwaUACU2vyUAPRRCAAmWux0IHAAFrwAhLYyNCicCIJsxAQAvBG6NPSMbADklQY1ADSRBSS1xTVSEsC5+RZQwZoIZTpU9dUIdfqMTS39tSGd0sAubr6Cod1AA

Comment: So it does error if you change the properties to being all required. Or even if you make only common optional on each interface.

Comment: TS is structural typing, and `One` and `Two` are the same structure, hence compatible and assignable to each other.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It's actually even more interesting than that... https://codesandbox.io/s/jnj79

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is that `One` and `Two` are mutually compatible types as you have defined them.

I don't know if there's a more canonical source of documentation for this, but the [(somewhat outdated) TypeScript specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3114-assignment-compatibility) says that all the properties of a target object type **T** are compatible with the analogous properties of a source type **S**, then a value of type **S** is assignable to variable of type **T**.

In your case, `One` is assignable to `Two` because:

- `Two`'s property `common` is an optional `string` value, and so is `One`'s; and
- `Two`'s property `two` is an optional `string` value, and `One` doesn't have a property of this name.

And `Two` is assignable to `One` for analogous reasons:

- `One`'s property `common` is an optional `string` value, and so is `Two`'s; and
- `One`'s property `one` is an optional `string` value, and `Two` doesn't have a property of this name.

This compatibility is possibly surprising.  TypeScript 2.4 introduced [weak type detection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) which will complain if you try to assign any value to an all-optional-property type like `One` or `Two` unless they share at least one property.  This prevents some crazy stuff like `{a?: string}` being compatible with `{b?: number}`, but in your case the fact that `common` exists in both `One` or `Two` disables the weak type checking.

---

My suggestion here is that if you have two types which are accidentally compatible, you can distinguish them by explicitly adding the problematic property keys to the other types as optional properties of type `never` or `undefined`:

```
export interface One {
  common?: string
  one?: string;
  two?: undefined;
}

export interface Two {
  common?: string
  one?: undefined;
  two?: string;
}
```

This isn't much different in terms of what you intend to assign to these types:

```
const one: One = {
  common: 'common',
  one: 'One'
}; // still okay

const two: Two = {
  common: 'common',
  two: 'Two'
} // still okay
```

but now the compiler sees `One` and `Two` as incompatible as desired:

```
func(one); // error!
//   ~~~ <--  Types of property 'one' are incompatible.
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeSTwG8AoOObCAW2oiQH4AuOAZximQHNy57hmbDtwDcvGAHcIggK5IAJsHTJg8sQF9SpUJFiIUaLLjgAVKXDIUqteoPackPCpOkt7ouL36yFSlWtJNbXBoeHQ5bBgEejhwpGwACkwoLhYzCABKC14Aehy4eQg2GmAYAAtuAEJArSokdj4iFkI8AF5sqxo6JBYAcmtu3oAaLya4XpbewLFSOoaXNPN2y0ou+j6B+mHxKT70qaC4xP4MkTg8uDQoaGqLigA-R7gAHgBaV4oTAE8wYFY+dBwMDXX6wL7jfi9ODJPDIaxgTBRABGABtgAA6IA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but we generate our typescript interfaces using openapi generator from yamls, so adding any extra properties wont' be feasible :(

Comment: Even if you generate interfaces programmatically you can always add extra properties in via [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).  Or you could probably modify your yaml to add the properties there.  Or you could leave the generated interfaces alone and make new interfaces which extend them with added properties.  Et cetera.  The point is: if you are writing any TS code at all you can likely do something to address the issue.  Good luck again!